# C Server/Client Echo

Tags: c, sockets

I tried to write an echo program for both server and client in C. The program look like below.
However, I always get "Could not connect to host" error. Is there any syntax error in my program?
I tried to follow the instructions on this thread
[C, Sockets: Connection Refused error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497716/c-sockets-connection-refused-error)
and the linux socket tutorial http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm,
but still got no lock. If anyone could shed lights on this, that would be greatly appreicated!

This is echoclient.c program.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* A buffer large enough to contain the longest allowed string */
#define BUFSIZE 218

#define USAGE                                                          \
  "usage:\n"                                                           \
  "  echoclient [options]\n"                                           \
  "options:\n"                                                         \
  "  -s                  Server (Default: localhost)\n"                \
  "  -p                  Port (Default: 10823)\n"                      \
  "  -m                  Message to send to server (Default: \"Hello " \
  "Summer.\")\n"                                                       \
  "  -h                  Show this help message\n"

static struct option gLongOptions[] = {
    {"server", required_argument, NULL, 's'},
    {"port", required_argument, NULL, 'p'},
    {"message", required_argument, NULL, 'm'},
    {"help", no_argument, NULL, 'h'},
    {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}};

/* Main ========================================================= */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int option_char = 0;
  char *hostname = "localhost";
  unsigned short portno = 10823;
  char *message = "Hello Summer!!";

  // Parse and set command line arguments
  while ((option_char = getopt_long(argc, argv, "s:p:m:hx", gLongOptions, NULL)) != -1) {
    switch (option_char) {
      case 's':  // server
        hostname = optarg;
        break;
      case 'p':  // listen-port
        portno = atoi(optarg);
        break;
      default:
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", USAGE);
        exit(1);
      case 'm':  // message
        message = optarg;
        break;
      case 'h':  // help
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", USAGE);
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
  }


  /* Socket Code Here */

  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  long nHostAddress;
  
  int socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  struct hostent* server=gethostbyname(hostname);
  memcpy(&nHostAddress, server->h_addr, server->h_length);
  
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=nHostAddress;
  
  char buff[16];
  connect(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr , sizeof(serv_addr));
  int len = send(socketfd, message, sizeof(message), 0);
  recv(socketfd, buff, len, 0);
  printf("%s", buff);
  close(socketfd);
  return 0;
  
}
```

This is echoserver.c program.

```
#define BUFSIZE 218

#define USAGE                                                        \
  "usage:\n"                                                         \
  "  echoserver [options]\n"                                         \
  "options:\n"                                                       \
  "  -p                  Port (Default: 10823)\n"                    \
  "  -m                  Maximum pending connections (default: 5)\n" \
  "  -h                  Show this help message\n"

static struct option gLongOptions[] = {
    {"port", required_argument, NULL, 'p'},
    {"maxnpending", required_argument, NULL, 'm'},
    {"help", no_argument, NULL, 'h'},
    {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int option_char;
  int portno = 10823; /* port to listen on */
  int maxnpending = 5;

  // Parse and set command line arguments
  while ((option_char =
              getopt_long(argc, argv, "p:m:hx", gLongOptions, NULL)) != -1) {
    switch (option_char) {
      case 'p':  // listen-port
        portno = atoi(optarg);
        break;
      default:
        fprintf(stderr, "%s ", USAGE);
        exit(1);
      case 'm':  // server
        maxnpending = atoi(optarg);
        break;
      case 'h':  // help
        fprintf(stdout, "%s ", USAGE);
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
  }


  /* Socket Code Here */
  
 char buff[16];
  struct addrinfo hints, *res, *rp;
  struct sockaddr_storage cli_addr;
  int sockfd;

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; 
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
  hints.ai_protocol = 0;
  
  char str[10];
  sprintf(str, "%d", portno);
  getaddrinfo(NULL, str, &hints, &res);
  // int sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
  
  for (rp = res; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
    sockfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);
    if (sockfd == -1)
        continue;

    if (bind(sockfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) == 0)
        break;                  /* Success */

    close(sockfd);
  }

  freeaddrinfo(res); 
  if (rp == NULL) {               /* No address succeeded */
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  // if(bind(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) < 0){
  //   printf("\nCould not connect to host\n");
  //   exit(1);
  // }
  
  if(listen(sockfd, maxnpending) < 0){
    printf("\nCould not listen\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  while(1){
    /* get the connected socket */
    socklen_t nAddressSize = sizeof(cli_addr);
    int hSocket = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &nAddressSize);
    if(hSocket < 0){
      printf("Accept fail\n");
      continue;
    }
    
    int len_recv = recv(hSocket, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
    if(len_recv < 0){
      printf("Receive fail\n");
      continue;
    }

    int len_send = send(hSocket, buff, len_recv, 0);
    if(len_send < 0){
      printf("Send fail\n");
      continue;
    }

    close(hSocket);
  }
  close(sockfd);
}
```

Comment: Your client connects to your server just fine for me. Perhaps there's a firewall stopping it on your computer? One note: Although the connection works fine, the sending/receiving does not. `message` is a `char*` and you send `sizeof(message)` bytes. `sizeof(message)` is a compiletime constant (most likely 4 or 8). You need to send the actual `strlen(message)` number of bytes. You must also be prepared that you can't send or receive full messages. They may be broken in parts.

Comment: Also remember, if you send `strlen(...)` bytes, the null-terminator won't be included in what is sent, and must be added on the receiving side.

Comment: And as always, you ***must*** check that all functions succeed!

Comment: The output of `ss -lunt '( sport = :80 )'` is always going to help, as will a tcpdump of the traffic. You also need to check the return of all those sys & library calls. I'm guessing at least one has failed.

Comment: For debugging, i would suggest to use `netstat` on the server side to check if there is a TCP socket in listening state on the port specified. Also flushing `iptables` or any firewall rules would be useful. I would also check the return value of `connect` in your client implementation, and in case of error, printing `strerror(errno)`.

Comment: What is `errno` (in errno.h) set to after the unsuccessful call to `bind`?